# How change number to month in data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a csv file like below.

```
year=c("2015","2016","2017")
month=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")
freq=c("10","12","16","12","21","16","23","22","20","19","21","15")
df=data.frame(year, month, freq)

ggplot(df, aes(x=month, y=freq, fill=year))+geom_bar(stat="identity)
```

axis.x showed `1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

I want `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`

How can i do?

Comment: Don't store strings of numbers. In this case, the strings are unfortunately converted to factors by `data.frame`, so you need to do `df$month <- as.integer(as.character(df$month))` to get them back to integers, though it's obviously better to just start with numbers. Same for your other columns.

Comment: This isn't a CSV file, you're creating a data frame from vectors. Does your real code read a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use factors. Try this before plotting:

```
df$month <- factor(month, levels = 1:12)
```

If you have to you can manually set the levels so `ggplot2` shall follow the order you picked.

Comment: `month` will already be a factor using the code in the question, since `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` was not specified. The issue is the ordering of levels.

Comment: I was building the answer haha. first I tried `month <- 1:12` only afterwards I fully reproduced the example. U did commented really fast though, well played.

Comment: I'm glad it did. Factors levels are also useful for violins, box, joy, basically any kind of binned visuals :D

Answer (score 0):

As @alistaire says, better to just start with numeric values in the first place, for `month` and all your other variables:

```
month <- 1:12
```

Then to get the correct labels on the x-axis, add this to the end of your `ggplot`:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```